# Print custom string upon unittest failure

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am using a for loop to iterate through a config file and pass variables within to a unit test.

```
for module in config:
        for testcase in config[module]:
            data = config[dict.keys(config)[0]][testcase]['foo']
            test_foo(self, data)
```

The problem with this method is the failures can be similar and are printed out at the end of testing. So there is no way to tell which variable it was that failed, only that n variables failed the test. Is there a way to print a custom string upon failure which would include the failed variable? Or perhaps there is even a better way to test the variables in my config file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can provide custom string in assert* method:

```
self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO', 'custom message')
```

This custom message will be printed on test failure

Comment: Didn't realise you could do that. Is there a way to include the variable name in custom message?

Comment: I guess you could pass a name of a variable into the test itself and format your message accordingly: self.assertTrue(var, '{} is not True'.format(var_name))

Comment: Silly followup question. I can just put the test variable name in the string eg 'custom message ' + foo

Comment: You'll want `str(foo)` if foo isn't a string.